# One-to-one dense function $C\to\mathbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $C$ be the Cantor set.

Is there a function $f:C\to \mathbb R$ such that $f$ is one-to-one and the graph of $f$ is dense in $C\times \mathbb R$?

Obviously I do not care about continuity.

I am fairly certain that the answer is yes.

My attempt is to let $\{U_i\times V_i:i\in\omega\}$ be a basis for $C\times \mathbb R$. For each $i\in\omega$ let $e_i\in U_i$. Recursively let $f(e_i)\in V_i$ such that $f(e_i)\neq f(e_j)$ for any $j<i$ (possible since each $V$ is uncountable). We have guaranteed that the graph will be dense.

Now let $C'=C\setminus \{e_i:i\in\omega\}$. Enumerate $C'=\{c_\alpha:\alpha<\mathfrak c\}$. For each $\alpha<\mathfrak c$ let $i_\alpha\in\omega$ such that $c_\alpha\in U_{i_\alpha}$, and pick $f(c_\alpha)\in V_{\alpha_i}$. Since each $V$ has size $\mathfrak c$, we can recursively choose the $f(c_\alpha)$'s to be distinct (and different from the $f(e_i)$'s).

This inductive method is not very slick. Any other ideas?

Comment: You can simplify your arguents a little: Start with $U_i\times V_i$, and choose, inductively, $(e_i,r_i)\in U_i\times V_i$ in such a manner that the sequences $(e_i)$, $(r_i)$ are injective (which can obviously be done). Now define $f(e_i)=r_i$. Now, since $|C|=|\mathbb{R}|=\mathfrak{c}$, we can extend $f$ to a bijection from $C$ to $\mathbb{R}$. You can argue that AC is not necessary, by using Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein and considering explicit countable dense subsets of the spaces, induction, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The method you outline will work, although as written it relies on the axiom of choice.

We can get rid of AC by just defining $f$ on a fixed countable dense subset of $C$, and letting $f$ be anything making $f$ injective off that subset. This gives a choiceless example, but still kind of nasty.

Comment: @ForeverMozart You're right, I missed the requirement of 1-1, and I think that kills a base-13 approach. But it's not hard to get it in the choiceless version.